# How to create auto-updating UWP package for sideloading in DevOps build or release pipelines?

Tags: uwp, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I've been reading about [auto-updates for sideloaded UWP apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2018/03/22/handling-auto-updates-for-sideloaded-uwp-and-desktop-bridge-apps/) and I'd like to explore this approach for one of our enterprise products. I can find [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/app-installer-root) for generating the `.appinstaller` from Visual Studio, but I cannot find documentation for generating it from DevOps/VSTS. Is there a way to do this? Perhaps a build parameter to `MSBuild`? Or a task in a release pipeline?

I know that we can use Visual Studio or make the file from scratch if we have to, but we are trying to use DevOps more and local builds less. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to turn on diagnostic logging for the build generated by Visual Studio. In doing so, I found the following MSBuild Arguments and added them to the build task in my DevOps build pipeline. The *new* arguments I had to add are bold below.

> /p:AppxPackageDir="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\AppxPackages\"
>   /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload 
>   /p:AppxBundlePlatforms="$(BuildPlatform)" /p:AppxBundle=Always
>   **/p:GenerateAppInstallerFile=true
>   /p:AppInstallerUri="http://localhost/MyPackageEndpoint"
>   /p:AppInstallerUpdateFrequency=1
>   /p:AppInstallerCheckForUpdateFrequency=OnApplicationRun**

With this, my output generates the *.appinstaller* file. My only issue is that I have to specify the URI, which I will have to manually change when I deploy this to different web servers for different environments. I might look into automated this with a script in a release pipeline.

Comment: Just addition. Turn on diagnostic logging in VS: Tools -> Options ->  Project and Solutions -> Build and Run -> MSBuild project build verbosity

Comment: @Alamakanambra, I have done this, but I cannot find command-line options VS uses with MSBuild.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do this? Perhaps a build parameter to MSBuild? Or a task in a release pipeline?

Yes, we should add some MSbuild arguments when we configure the build task in DevOps Build pipeline:

```
/p:AppxPackageDir="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\AppxPackages\\"
/p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload
/p:AppxBundlePlatforms="$(Build.BuildPlatform)"
/p:AppxBundle=Always
```

[image]

Check the document [Set up automated builds for your UWP app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/auto-build-package-uwp-apps#set-up-a-continuous-deployment-build-for-sideloading) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't answer my question of how to generate the *.appinstaller* file. I found it on my own and posted an answer.